# NSInvalidArgumentException error with Phonegap 2.1 and facebook plugin

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been following the facebook phonegap plugin install instructions here: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect.

After taking my time and follow every step very closely, I was able to build the project successfully in the simulator in xcode. I am using phonegap 2.1, which I downloaded off of the phonegap site, NOT directly from github.

The splash screen loads fine, but once the app goes to run this is the output from xcode:

> 2012-10-15 17:04:40.604 NeighborFavor[1648:19a03] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
>
> 2012-10-15 17:04:40.606 NeighborFavor[1648:19a03] -[__NSCFDictionary >dictionaryWithLowercaseKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1943a0
>
> 2012-10-15 17:04:40.607 NeighborFavor[1648:19a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught >exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary >dictionaryWithLowercaseKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1943a0'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x2a32012 0x2445e7e 0x2abd4bd 0x2a21bbc 0x2a2194e 0xbfc9 0xb39e 0xb5a5 0x3939 0x73446e >0xb63e 0x3250 0x6527b7 0x652da7 0x653fab 0x665315 0x66624b 0x657cf8 0x294edf9 0x294ead0 >0x29a7bf5 0x29a7962 0x29d8bb6 0x29d7f44 0x29d7e1b 0x6537da 0x65565c 0x2ef6 0x2e25 0x1)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Any help would be great thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `-load_all` to your `Other Linker Flags` in Xcode? Without that flag categories in external libraries/frameworks aren't loaded and `dictionaryWithLowercaseKeys` is no standard method that Apple would offer for Dictionaries, it is most likely a method added by a category (an extension to a class that adds additional methods to it at runtime).

Comment: Thank you for your response it was an issue with my other linker flags! I was making a mistake on step 9 where I am suppose to add -lsqlite3.0.  I was adding an entirely new attribute under the other linker flags.  Where I should have just adding it in at the end of string.  Once I clicked on the value, rather than adding a new key/value pair, I noticed you can add an attribute within the string. Thank you so much for your help you definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I was making a mistake on step 9 following the ios tuturial https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect.

The other linker flags value should look like this after your done

> -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -all_load -Obj-C -lsqlite3.0

Notice the -lsqlite3.0 at the end of the string rather than adding it as a new key/value pair. Once I changed this it worked. Thanks again for the help.